# Por que minha pergunta foi sinalizada como pendente?

Tags: suporte

Fiz [uma pergunta sobre armazenar saída do CMD em um arquivo txt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238315/armazenando-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-sistema-operacional-e-hardware-em-um-arquivo):

E nela envolve sim programação e inclusive achei uma solução mas que esta me dando problema  que é [essa outra.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239355/raise-keyerrorkey-from-none-keyerror-tcl-lib-py-para-exe)

Não sei se o modo como perguntei está incorreto mas acredito que a pergunta seja referente ao escopo da comunidade, ou não?

Comment: A pergunta sua está muito confusa, geralmente a comunidade marca como off-topic mesmo. E as vezes, mesmo uma pergunta sendo sobre programação, ela ainda pode ser fora de escopo.

Comment: Entendi, acho que tinha que ser mais direto então. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Answer (score 8):

Primeiro, sua pergunta estava muito confusa de se entender, você cita:

> Preciso fazer o mapeamento dos computadores na empresa onde trabalho e preciso ir de maquina em maquina para relacionar o ip ao usuário.

A sua "resposta" (postada no corpo da pergunta) inclusive leva a entender que na verdade o mapeamento não era o problema em si, mas creio que isto foi o que causou a maior parte da confusão.

Seu texto também contém redundâncias de que nada ajudam a compreender o problema:

> Boa tarde,
>   tenho um problema e gostaria de resolver da forma mais pratica possível.

Creio eu que todos que veem aqui com uma pergunta tem "um problema" e gostariam de resolver da "melhor maneira possível", não precisa dizer o que é praticamente implícito.

Já esse ponto pra mim foi o que você conseguiu expressar perfeitamente:

> Porem me foi exigido também recolher informações do sistema como o processador que usa, a quantidade de RAM, e a arquitetura do S.O.(São todas Windows).

No entanto isto ficaria melhor em tópicos, algo como:

> Preciso recolher as seguintes infos:
>
> - Quantidade de RAM
> - Modelo do processador
> - Sistema operacional e arquitetura

Pra resumir a pergunta **não é de todo mal**, mas da maneira que foi escrita causou incertezas (eu fui um dos que votei para fechar), quero que entenda uma coisa Perguntas fechadas não são perguntas banidas, pense no fechamento como uma bloqueio temporário até que o autor resolva as pendencias de possiveis problemas na pergunta, ou seja ela pode ser reaberta.

Agora sobre a sua edição:

> EDIT:
>
> Galera, depois do comentario do
>   @gfleck(https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/59504/gfleck) e de
>   pesquisar um pouco, consegui resolver! Segue o Codigo em Python para a
>   resolução:
>
> ```
> import subprocess
> import socket
> import os
>
> host = socket.gethostname()
> ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
> os.system("systeminfo /s "+ip+"> config.txt ")
> ```

O **corpo da pergunta** não é local de se colocar respostas, você é novo na comunidade e o principal é entender que isso não é um fórum e nem helpdesk, é um Q&A e a ferramenta (site) proporciona que você organize as postagens em seus devidos lugares, **eu entendo** perfeitamente que a pergunta esta bloqueada e você não pode clicar no botão <kbd>Publica sua resposta</kbd>, mas é como eu já disse, se esta bloqueada e com pendencia você deve ler o conteudo do "box amarelo".

No caso a sua foi marcada como **fora do escopo**, mas foi um fechamento errôneo do **meu ponto de vista**, o mais apropriado seria **Não esta clara**, no entanto já falei isso também em outras postagens, todos, todos mesmo, adm, cm, usuário, moderadores, todos podem errar e tem esse direito e não tem porque ninguém se exaltar, a não ser que sejam erros repetitivos, mas a questão agora é resolver a sua pergunta e quando estiver dentro do conformes ela passa por uma "triagem" aonde é avaliada se pode ser reaberta.

Para entrar na triagem o ideal, creio eu, é editar a a pergunta seguindo dicas nos comentários (se recebeu algum) tentar clarear a pergunta e dependendo da ação ela entra sozinha na triagem, no entanto não posso afirmar, mas acho que você pode votar para reabrir suas próprias perguntas fechadas (não me recordo como funciona com score baixo)

---

### Conclusão

Editei a pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/238315/revisions, votei para reabrir e dei um upvote.

Agora cabe a você ter mais atenção e foco nas perguntas futuras.

Comment: Agora sim realmente percebi os erros. Fico muito grato pela compreensão e pela atenção, pode deixar que nas próximas perguntas serei mais claro seguindo o exemplo da sua edição.

Comment: Pra mim tá ampla, não tem nada, só um desejo do que quer fazer.

Comment: @bigown entendo, é bem provavel mesmo, tentei reduzir e focar no que melhor pude, não sei se fiz o melhor ou ideal, fiz o que pude para ajudar, creio que agora só cabe ao autor definir o resto (tentar melhorar)